# How to check for an array of items of table B in table A? (without using loops)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I need to find if an id in Table A is equal to ANY of many IDs in Table B. Can I do it without using any loops?
Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM tableA AS a WHERE a.location_id IN (SELECT b.location_id FROM tableB AS b)
```

I have the following data:

Table A has : user_id, location_id

Table B has: admin_id, location_id

In Table B admin_id and location_id forms together a composite key. That means that admin can have multiple locations.

In Table A user_id is unique but location_id is not. I need to find if location_id from Table A matches to ANY of the location_id in Table B. How can I do that? Can it only be done using loops?

Comment: Your query should work.  What is your question?

Comment: FWIW: the `IN` and subquery can be re-written in terms of a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach with `in` should work. I would, however, recommend using `exists`:

```
select * 
from tablea as a 
where exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.location_id = a.location_id)
```

`not exists` usually scales better when the number elements in `b` increases - especially if you have an index on `tableb(location_id)`.

Comment: whats select 1 ?

Comment: @B.S.: `exists` just checks if *some row* exists that satisfy the conditions, we don't care about the actual results - so `select 1`.

Comment: I tried but it only fetches one result from TableA where in fact there are Two that matches location_id to TableB location_id

Comment: @B.S.: that would be suprising. This query should give you the very same results as your solution, but possibly faster. Are you able to set up a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) that demonstrates the problem?